# Перевод времени в дату и обратно в разных форматах

Tags: android, дата

Вынужден задать такой вопрос, ибо поиски не дали четких ответов. Имеем

```
 long some_time; // некое время в миллисекундах с начала 1970 года,
    // например,  полученное таким образом: some_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
 int sec, min, hour, day, mounth, year; // значения соответствующих отрезков времени, для которых верно следующее:
 // время, например, 23:18:59 31.12.2015 - это:
 // sec = 59;
 // min = 18;
 // hour = 23;
 // day = 31;
 // month = 12;
 // year = 2015;
```

Вопрос #1: известно

```
some_time
```

приведите, пожалуйста, полный код, как получить

```
sec, min, hour, day, mounth, year
```

Обратный вопрос #2: известно

```
 sec, min, hour, day, mounth, year
```

- какой код даст

```
some_time
```

То же для строк. Широко известно, что так

```
String date_str = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd.MM.yyyy").format(some_time);
```

можно получить строку с датой в заданном формате. Вопрос #3: А как из строки

```
date_str
```

получить при том же формате

```
some_time
```

Comment: С телефона ответ не написать, но вас точно устроит класс Calendar

Comment: А миллисек из строки просто. Преобразовываете в Date и... Все.

Answer (score 3):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(some_time);
```

так достаются значения:

```
calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 
calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Так обратно:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(yourDateFormat, Locale.ENGLISH).parse(dateText);
long milliseconds = date.getTime();
```

Comment: Пронумеровал вопросы. Вы ответили на вопрос №1 и 3. Как решить вопрос №2?

Comment: @St-st Можно немного и своей же головой поработать, правда. Класс `Calendar` имеет не только геттеры, но и сеттеры. Устанавливаете сеттером `set(int year, int month, int day, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second)` в экземпляр календаря свои минуты часы дни и тд и забираете геттером `getTimeInMillis()` результат - действие обратное первому варианту.

Comment: @pavlofff К большому сожалению, думая головой, тяжело угадать канонически верный синтаксис. Понятно, что есть обратный метод. Но какой его синтаксис? Такой как Вы указали: set(int year, int month, int day, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second), или такой: calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)? Думаю и для других читателей будет полезно увидеть несколько строчек кода для конкретного примера, полностью закрывающего вопрос.

Comment: @Андроид Андроид, проясните, пожалуйста, какую роль в выражении 'Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(yourDateFormat, Locale.ENGLISH).parse(dateText);' играет параметр Locale.ENGLISH, и что это такое?

Comment: Локаль передается для отображения даты и времени соответствующим образом на выходе. Вообще, в Вашем случае, его можно не передавать. Да и сам формат тоже думаю смысла указывать нет. То есть из всех четырех конструкторов этого класса для Вас подойдет пустой. Читните оффдок, там вроде бы все понятно расписано

Comment: По времени и календарю все прояснилось благодаря Вашему импульсу. Даты не рассматривал, так как и устарели (устаревают), и не вижу надобности если есть время юникс, календарь и форматирование, кроме как получить время из строки по Вашему примеру. SimpleDateFormat - преобразовывает в строку время С УЧЕТОМ часового пояса. Вот с этой локалью, которая у Вас указана, я и не разобрался. "Локаль для отображения соответствующим образом". Я думал, соответствующий образ - это часовой пояс, и искал константу, которая оставляет ЮТС часовой пояс, но не нашел.

Comment: Приходится использовать следующую конструкцию: `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ( "HH:mm:ss" );
format . setTimeZone ( new SimpleTimeZone ( SimpleTimeZone . UTC_TIME , "UTC" ));`